# Apache RewriteRule for removing tailing slash only at root

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite

I know there are many questions about Apache RewriteRules, especially for removing trailing slashes. I have looked at tons but I can't seem to find anyone trying to solve this problem.

I am using Magento, so the URL structure looks like this:

- example.com/index.php
- example.com/index.php/
- example.com/index.php/page1/

Here is my ideal URL structure:

- example.com
- example.com/page1/
- example.com/page2/

So basically I just want to strip the index.php AND make sure the naked domain does not have a trailing slash (example.com instead of example.com/). Also, I would like to NOT include the hardcoded domain name if possible so that the rewrite can be applied in different environments.

Here is my current Rewrite...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php/?
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

This seems to work in all situations, except for:

- example.com/index.php (doesn't work at all)
- example.com/index.php/ (leaves the trailing slash)

I would appreciate any regex advice! Thank you.

---

**UPDATE**
Thanks to the answer below from @zx81 I have successfully stripped all URLs down to the root domain, but still can't remove the slash.

So here is the current URL: example.com/

And I can't remove the trailing slash!

Answer (score 1):

Not able to test it live, but try this.

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php()/?(?:([^/]+)/)? $1$2 [R=301,L]
```

1. It should handle the one that doesn't work at all thanks to the empty capturing group 1 `()`.
2. In PCRE (Apache's regex flavor) this also strips the trailing slash, but Apache may decide to add it back.

Comment: @mtaube in addition to this regex to take care of the path that was not redirecting, you may want to look at the [directory slash directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) if slashes are left at the root.

Comment: thank you sir! You're right, the regex does take care of that path. I still can't figure out the trailing slash on the root domain though, Apache doesn't like the idea at all. But not giving up yet!